# Parent node output on if child of sibling node exists XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to get an output of a parent node that has the same contents of a certain element in another XML file. I am new to XSLT so I am hoping you can help me point out my mistake.

Here is my external xml: "XML2.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <section>
        <sub-section>
            <chapter>Chapter 1</chapter>
        </sub-section>
        <sub-sectionB>
            <author>Author 1A</author>
            <author>Author 2B</author>
        </sub-sectionB> 
    </section>
    <section>
        <sub-section>
            <chapter>Chapter 2</chapter>
        </sub-section>
        <sub-sectionB>
            <author>Author 1D</author>
            <author>Author 2C</author>
        </sub-sectionB> 
     </section>
</root>
```

My Main XML: XML1.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rules>
    <somerules>
        <rule1>Author 1A</rule1>
    </somerules>
    <somerules>
        <rule1>Author 1C</rule1>
    </somerules>
</rules>
```

My XSLT attempt: XMLRULES.xslt

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="xinput" select="document('XML2.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="var1" select="$xinput/root/section/sub-sectionB/author"/>            
            <xsl:for-each select="/rules/somerules/rule1[(.=$var1)]">
                <xsl:value-of select="$xinput/root/section/sub-section/chapter"/>
            </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current HTML output:

```
Chapter1 Chapter2
```

My desired HTML output is to get the text:

```
Chapter1
```

from the sub-section node `if Author1A (from XML1 file) = Author 1A (from XML2 file)`

What i am getting now is a list of all Chapters. how can I just get Chapter1?

Comment: What would be the expected result if both "Author 1A" and "Author 1C" appeared in Chapter 1. Would you want Chapter 1 output twice or once?

Comment: @TimC I would want Chapter 1 to appear only once if that was the expected result

Answer (score 1):

For cross-references I would set up a key (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#key) with `xsl:key` and use the `key` function, in particular as you seem to be using XSLT 2 where you can easily use the third argument of that function to pass in the subtree or document you want to search.

So the key definition could be

```
  <xsl:key name="chapter-ref" match="section/sub-section/chapter" use="../../sub-sectionB/author"/>
```

then you can simply select

```
  <xsl:value-of select="key('chapter-ref', rules/somerules/rule1, $doc2)"/>
```

full stylesheet would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="doc2">
<root>
    <section>
        <sub-section>
            <chapter>Chapter 1</chapter>
        </sub-section>
        <sub-sectionB>
            <author>Author 1A</author>
            <author>Author 2B</author>
        </sub-sectionB> 
    </section>
    <section>
        <sub-section>
            <chapter>Chapter 2</chapter>
        </sub-section>
        <sub-sectionB>
            <author>Author 1D</author>
            <author>Author 2C</author>
        </sub-sectionB> 
     </section>
</root>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="chapter-ref" match="section/sub-section/chapter" use="../../sub-sectionB/author"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:value-of select="key('chapter-ref', rules/somerules/rule1, $doc2)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTE/1, the second document is inline there for the compactness of the example but you could of course as well use `<xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc('xml2.xml')"/>`.